# Looking for medrash regarding briyas ha'adam

Tags: midrash, adam

I've heard referenced a medrash that says at the time of brias ha'adam, the melachim were so taken aback by adam that they thought maybe it was a type of deity, or that they should be worshiping him in some way.

Does anyone know of such a medrash?

Thanks

Comment: Breishis Rabbah 8:10

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Avrah who said [Bereshes Rabbah 8:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.8.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> אמר רבי הושעיא, בשעה שברא הקדוש ברוך הוא אדם הראשון טעו מלאכי השרת
> ובקשו לומר לפניו קדוש. משל למלך ואפרכוס שהיו בקרוכין, והיו בני המדינה
> מבקשין לומר למלך דומינו, ולא היו יודעין איזהו, מה עשה המלך דחפו
> והוציאו חוץ לקרוכין, וידעו הכל שהוא אפרכוס. כך בשעה שברא הקדוש ברוך
> הוא את אדם הראשון, טעו בו מלאכי השרת ובקשו לומר לפניו קדוש. מה עשה
> הקדוש ברוך הוא, הפיל עליו תרדמה וידעו הכל שהוא אדם. הדא הוא דכתיב
> (ישעיה ב, כב): חדלו לכם מן האדם אשר נשמה באפו כי במה נחשב הוא.